# I am having trouble with my stack build, I have tried uninstalling, and running on administrator

Tags: linux, haskell, stack, ghci

I need to build a haskell programm for an assignment and I tried to run to run stack build and got a failure message like this

Stack has not been tested with GHC versions above 8.10, and using 9.4.7, this may fail
Preparing to install GHC (tinfo6) to an isolated location.
This will not interfere with any system-level installation.
Downloaded ghc-tinfo6-9.4.7.
Unpacking GHC into /root/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-tinfo6-9.4.7
Did not find executable at specified path: /root/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-tinfo6-9.4.7.temp/ghc-9.4.7/configure

Error: Error encountered while configuring GHC with
/root/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-tinfo6-9.4.7.temp/ghc-9.4.7/configure --prefix=/root/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-tinfo6-9.4.7/
run in /root/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-tinfo6-9.4.7.temp/ghc-9.4.7/

```
   The following directories may now contain files, but won't be used by stack:
     - /root/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-tinfo6-9.4.7.temp/
     - /root/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-tinfo6-9.4.7/

   For more information consider rerunning with --verbose flag
```

Configuring GHC ...

I used the --verbose flag and it honestly was not helpful at all, I also tried to run as administrator, how would I go about solving this problem.

Comment: How did you [install](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/install_and_upgrade/#install-stack) stack? which [version](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/global_flags/#-version-flag) of it are you using? do you have a global version of ghc installed? which [resolver](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/stack_yaml_vs_cabal_package_file/#resolvers-and-snapshots) are you using?

Comment: Looks like you're using a really old version of `stack`. Using it with GHC>8.10 has not resulted in this warning for close to 3 years – but you're trying to use it with a much newer version of ghc. Looks like it's trying to build ghc from source here, and you probably don't have the development libraries. You'll probably want to use an up to date `stack`, which you can either get from `stackage` or via `ghcup`. You're probably on something like an old version of Ubuntu with an outdated stack page and trying to build a much newer project.